# Using FindbyID method in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, findby

Having some issues using FindByID method in C#.

The program will not recognize the `FindBy` method when written out as below. No other parts of the code produce an error.

```cs
Database3DataSet.MemlistRow customerRow = Database3DataSet.MemlistDataTable.FindByID(Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));
```

Examples seem to show the second half of the equation as

```cs
Database3DataSet.Memlist.FindByID(Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));
```

e.g. not as a datatable. But this does not seem to be an option. Also Solution Explorer seems to show that DataTable is equal to table. So maybe this is a change present in Visual Studio 2022?

Furthermore I cannot declare anything a Dim as this does not seem to be recognized as a method.

I tried using the Select method but I cannot get this to work either. The help for this also seem to show the table called Memlist input and just that, not MemlistDataTable. so I wonder if this is the same problem.

I could actually get FindByID to be recognized as a method through different, simpler coding, but could not get further parts to work and I have lost the simple piece of code that got me there.

Comment: *"... I cannot declare anything as Dim"* ... If you're trying to `Dim` you want VB.Net, not C#.

Comment: Ah it is, updated

Comment: I downloaded a working project, quit, ran the working one, quit, started my project and now get less errors. Still getting Compiler Error CS0120 as the only one though. Help says An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'

In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must first create an object instance. Which I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an instance of the DataTable above this code using
var mc = new Database3DataSet.MemlistDataTable();